# How can I make this match a directory given

Tags: ruby, regex

```
currDir = ""
# 
# regex is from stack overflow question:
dirRegex = Regexp.new '^(?!.*[\\/]\.{2}[\\/])(?!\.{2}[\\/])[-\w.\\/]+$'
if ARGV.length == 1 && $1.to_s.match dirRegex
  currDir = $1
  puts $1
  puts "#{currDir}"
  puts ARGV.length
else
  currDir = "./"
  puts $1
  puts "#{currDir}"
  puts ARGV.length
end
```

When I try to have the above code match a directory such as home or ~/test/ it gives me an error.

```
./script.rb /home/local/NKU/dixonc3/test
./script.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
./script.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting $end
```

Comment: You could fix also by writing this way ..`ARGV.length == 1 && ($1.to_s.match dirRegex)`.. Due to higher precedence `&&`, `ARGV.length == 1 && $1.to_s.match dirRegex` is being treated as `(ARGV.length == 1 && $1.to_s.match) dirRegex`.. here it raises *BooM! BooM!!!!* :-)

Comment: I'm still having a problem with my parameters though.  Let me know if this needs a separate question.  if I just pass it my home directory ~ it says "can't convert nil into string"

Comment: yes.. separate question.. by accepting this answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
if ARGV.length == 1 && $1.to_s.match dirRegex # line 5
```

to:

```
if ARGV.length == 1 && $1.to_s.match(dirRegex)
```

Comment: Yes.. +1... That;s the answer

Comment: @Agis I can't believe it's that simple.  :(